# Visual Basic get clicked element in iFrame

Tags: html, vb.net, iframe, webbrowser-control

I made a custom Browser using the VB.NET framework to get the elements of a document. For a simple summary each time I clicked an element documentClicked will display a message, but when I click elements inside an iFrame it doesn't give me any data.

I figured that since doc is an HtmlDocument and an iframe would be an HtmlWindow or something along those lines; that's why it is not working but I am unsure how to go about declaring this.

Essentially I just want to be able to click any element on any page and it'll display the coordinates and size - works fine with everything but elements inside an iFrame.

```
Dim WithEvents doc As HtmlDocument

    Private Sub WinBrowse_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles webBrowser.DocumentCompleted
            doc = CType(sender, WebBrowser).Document
    End Sub

     Private Sub doc_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs) Handles doc.Click
            documentClicked(webBrowser, e)
     End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a complete answer, but in my experience the VB WebBrowser control isn't a full-blown browser - it is just a VB control that makes use of the resident IE browser engine to display straightforward HTML pages.

Some things are beyond its capabilities (try using contenteditable with it).

I've not tried iframe but it wouldn't surprise me if it didn't like it - it is really quite limited.

Comment: I am able to automatically get elements in the iFrame by finding all the iFrames on the webpage and then finding the element. Essentially I just need to have a iFrameClicked sub that will generate the iFrame (HTMLWIndow) instead of the HTMLDocument. To my understanding.

Comment: OK - that sounds promising... if you can get iframe elements then you probably just need to identify them properly within the iframe document (which is a whole separate document from the container HTML document).

Without seeing your code, I can't suggest much else.

Comment: First off, this is only possible if the iframe and parent page are in the same document domain. If they are not you are going to get an Unauthorized access exception when you try to do events for the Iframe's document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very much on the right track. Now, as I said in my comment, this will only work if both the Iframe and the parent window are in the same document domain, otherwise you will get an unauthorized access exception.

I am also assuming you have only 1 iframe on this page, if not you will have to loop through the list and identify the correct one.

VB

```
    Public Class Form2
        Dim WithEvents IframeDoc As HtmlDocument
        Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
            If (WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Then
                Dim doc = WebBrowser1.Document
                Dim window = doc.Window
                Dim IframeWindow = window.Frames(0)
                IframeDoc = IframeWindow.Document
            End If
        End Sub
        Private Sub Document_Click(sender As Object, e As HtmlElementEventArgs) Handles IframeDoc.Click
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToElement.ToString())
        End Sub
    End Class
```

C#

```
       private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
          var doc=   webBrowser1.Document;
            var window = webBrowser1.Document.Window;
            var iframewindow = window.Frames[0]; //I am assuming its the first one
            MessageBox.Show(iframewindow.Document.Domain);

        }
    }

    private void Document_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToElement.ToString());
    }
```

You are welcome to simplify the variable declarations.

Comment: This was just the grounding I needed to be able to achieve what I needed! Thank you!